# What is the issue with this code using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've just started using prepared statements in this code, but I'm having a problem.  I'm using them to see if a user with a certain email already exists, but it won't work.  Here's my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mypass", "mydb");

$uname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["uname"]);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$passwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["passwd"]);

$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt1->execute();
$res1 = $stmt1->get_result();
$i = 0;
while($row1 = $res1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i = $i + 1;
}
if($i != 0) {
    die("A user with that email already exists.");
}
```

I then go on to check if the username is already in use using the same code, just swapping out the references to email with uname and switching stmt1 to stmt2.  What's wrong with my code here?

Comment: Don't escape if you're using prepared statements.... that's one of the things that prepared statements do for you

Comment: If you are using prepared statements, you shouldn't be using `real_escape_string`. Prepared statements handle that part for you.

Comment: "It won't work" means you have no results and although your error_reporting is set properly you have no error message, right?

Comment: The real_escape_string's not the problem, it still won't work.  And to Markus, I'm sending the data to the page using AJAX (jQuery).  It executes the function I set for when it fails, but I know it's not a problem with the jQuery because everything works fine if I comment out this section of code.

Comment: We don't have access to your server or database so we can't know what "doesn't work" if you don't tell us.

Comment: Maybe you have to init your statment with `$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what's not working, except that it's a problem with this section.  There is no error message of any kind and everything works fine if I remove this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the page for the Login which I use for my website. Better you make according changes for you requirements.

```
<?php
global $con;;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", 'rvani', "rv6861", TRUE) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("rvani", $con);

/// Connection

$pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);`enter code here`
if($pwd == ""){
    echo'PasswordNull';
    return;
    }
if($email == ""){
    echo'EmailNull';
    return;
    }
$quy = "select * from MLogin where email_id='$email'";
global $con;
try {
    $res= mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($quy, $con));
    }
catch (Exception $e1)
    {
    echo 'Error';
    }
if(md5($pwd) === $res['Password']){
    //echo'Successfully';
    echo'Welcome';
    return ;
}else{
    echo'PasswordNotMatch';
    return ;
}    
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
?>
```

Comment: I believe the question is asking to find the issue in the given code base.